# Take an array and a letter as arguments and return a new array with words that contain that letter

Tags: ruby, arrays

I can run a search and find the element I want and can return those words with that letter. But when I start to put arguments in, it doesn't work. I tried `select` with `include?` and it throws an error saying, private method. This is my code, which returns what I am expecting:

```
my_array = ["wants", "need", 3, "the", "wait", "only", "share", 2]

def finding_method(source)
    words_found = source.grep(/t/) #I just pick random letter
    print words_found
end

puts finding_method(my_array)
# => ["wants", "the", "wait"]
```

I need to add the second argument, but it breaks:

```
def finding_method(source, x)
    words_found = source.grep(/x/)
    print words_found
end

puts finding_method(my_array, "t")
```

This doesn't work, (it returns an empty array because there isn't an `'x'` in the array) so I don't know how to pass an argument. Maybe I'm using the wrong method to do what I'm after. I have to define `'x'`, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions support string interpolation just like strings.

```
/x/
```

looks for the character `x`.

```
/#{x}/
```

will first interpolate the value of the variable and produce `/t/`, which does what you want. Mostly.

Note that if you are trying to search for any text that might have any meaning in regular expression syntax (like `.` or `*`), you should escape it:

```
/#{Regexp.quote(x)}/
```

That's the correct answer for any situation where you are including literal strings in regular expression that you haven't built yourself specifically for the purpose of being a regular expression, i.e. 99% of cases where you're interpolating variables into regexps.